# Windows Can not find some files On DVD

Tags: windows-7, dvd

I have some DVDs which have autorun. When I input them, an error will be shown, It is "Windows can not find H:\Autorun\Setup.exe"

Why is it like this? and how to fix it?

Comment: Is your DVD drive H:?  Does \autorun\setup.exe exist on the DVD's? Are these specific DVDs, or does it do this for any/every DVD?

Comment: yes the files exist. because I have tested DVDs on another PC. and for many of DVDs it happens, but on some no. So?

Comment: Were the other machines Windows 7 as well?

Comment: Yes, Of course, they are 7 too.

Comment: If it's only a problem on one computer, perhaps it has a faulty DVD player. Perhaps yank the DVD player out of the computer it works with and try it in the problematic computer?  Also, perhaps edit your question and include the contents of your `Autorun.inf` file(s).

Comment: I have re-assembled DVD-Rom, but it does not solved the problem, Let explain more, the DVD has an autorun.exe itself, it will run, then for example it has some buttons for running applications, button 1 is for setup.exe, when I click on button, that error will be shown. and another tip, DVD is copy-protection and setup.exe is hidden. But this DVD has no problem on other systems... So?